# Generate Array of Numbers that fit to a Probability Distribution in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, prng, sciruby

Say I have 100 records, and I want to mock out the `created_at` date so it fits on some curve.  Is there a library to do that, or what formula could I use?  I think this is along the same track:

[Generate Random Numbers with Probabilistic Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109670/generate-random-numbers-with-probabilistic-distribution)

I don't know much about how they are classified in mathematics, but I'm looking at things like:

- bell curve
- logarithmic (typical biology/evolution) curve?
  ...

Just looking for some formulas in code so I can say this:

- Given 100 records, a timespan of `1.week`, and an interval of `12.hours`
- set `created_at` for each record such that it fits, roughly, to `curve`

Thanks so much!

**Update**

I found [this forum post about ruby algorithms](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/104729), which led me to [rsruby](https://github.com/alexgutteridge/rsruby), an R/Ruby bridge, but that seems like too much.

**Update 2**

I wrote this little snippet trying out the `gsl` library, getting there...

[Generate test data in Rails where created_at falls along a Statistical Distribution](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/12793)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate UNIX timestamps which are really just integers.  First figure out when you want to start, for example now:

```
start = DateTime::now().to_time.to_i
```

Find out when the end of your interval should be (say 1 week later):

```
finish = (DateTime::now()+1.week).to_time.to_i
```

Ruby uses [this algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) to generate random numbers. It is almost uniform.  Then generate random numbers between the two:

```
r = Random.new.rand(start..finish)
```

Then convert that back to a date:

```
d = Time.at(r)
```

---

This looks promising as well:
http://rb-gsl.rubyforge.org/files/rdoc/randist_rdoc.html

And this too:
http://rb-gsl.rubyforge.org/files/rdoc/rng_rdoc.html

Comment: but that won't fit a particular distribution

Comment: see the added links above - they look helpful

Answer (score 4):

I recently came across [croupier](https://github.com/xuanxu/croupier), a ruby gem that aims to generate numbers according to a variety of statistical distributions.

I have yet to try it but it sounds quite promising.

Comment: I use this to generate random normal data in ruby and it's really good.

Answer (score 0):

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Generation_from_a_probability_distribution):

> There are a couple of methods to
>   generate a random number based on a
>   probability density function. These
>   methods involve transforming a uniform
>   random number in some way. Because of
>   this, these methods work equally well
>   in generating both pseudo-random and
>   true random numbers.
>
> One method, called the [inversion
>   method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), involves integrating up to
>   an area greater than or equal to the
>   random number (which should be
>   generated between 0 and 1 for proper
>   distributions).
>
> A second method, called the
>   [acceptance-rejection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling),
>   involves choosing an x and y value and
>   testing whether the function of x is
>   greater than the y value. If it is,
>   the x value is accepted. Otherwise,
>   the x value is rejected and the
>   algorithm tries again.

The first method is the one used in the accepted answer in your SO linked question: [Generate Random Numbers with Probabilistic Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109670/generate-random-numbers-with-probabilistic-distribution)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the [Distribution](https://github.com/sciruby/distribution) gem under [SciRuby](http://sciruby.com). You can generate normal numbers by:

```
require 'distribution'

rng = Distribution::Normal.rng
random_numbers = Array.new(100).map { rng.call }
```

There are RNGs for various other distributions as well.