# Is there a scientific library for generating probability distributions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, statistics, sciruby

Is there a scientific library in JavaScript that can generate probability distributions like this library in Ruby?

http://rb-gsl.rubyforge.org/

For more details on the use cases see this related question: [Generate Array of Numbers that fit to a Probability Distribution in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550758/generate-array-of-numbers-that-fit-to-a-probability-distribution-in-ruby)

Comment: There's [jstat](http://www.jstat.org); not much documentation, questionable code (if you were to ask for my opinion ;-)

Comment: Why not make an API wrapper around Ruby GSL by using say, Sinatra, then call that API from your browser using `jQuery.ajax`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For generating distributions in JavaScript, see [stdlib](https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib/tree/88c1a0ca14e19162600ecf0ec6530f2b3902f0e0/lib/node_modules/%40stdlib/math/base/random), which includes seedable PRNGs for many distributions.

Answer (score -1):

From what I've been reading, some R defectors are moving toward a library called [Julia](http://julialang.org/). It's been ported to Javascript **[here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/test/perf/perf.js)** by the makers of Julia themselves, and it looks quite promising.

**[The Julia Language](http://julialang.org/)**

Comment: Also, read this interesting write-up: [The Best Statistical Programming Language is …Javascript?](http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-best-statistical-programming-language-is-%E2%80%A6javascript/)