# How to generate a random number with a specific probability density function?

Tags: java, random, probability-theory

I am trying to model shadowing and fast fading for mobile wireless networks. For fast fading, Rayleigh fading is a reasonable model to use. The envelope of the channel response will be Rayleigh distributed. Calling this random variable R, it will have a probability density function (PDF) of

PR(r) = ((2r)/Ω)*exp(-r^2/Ω), r >= 0, Ω = 2σ^2

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_fading to see the equation written nicely.

So, I have the PDF, now I am just wondering how to get the random variable from it?

I have looked at these questions:

[Generate Array of Numbers that fit to a Probability Distribution in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550758/generate-array-of-numbers-that-fit-to-a-probability-distribution-in-ruby)

[Generate Random Numbers with Probabilistic Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109670/generate-random-numbers-with-probabilistic-distribution)

but I am still not sure how to do it. It has taken me forever to understand PDF's so if anyone knows a way in Java to get a random variable with a specific PDF, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rayleigh distribution is a special case of the [Weibull distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution). If you google around, there are lots of Weibull generators written in Java, for example:

- http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/WeibullDistribution.html
- http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/ssj/doc/html/umontreal/iro/lecuyer/randvar/WeibullGen.html
- http://www.icsa.inf.ed.ac.uk/research/groups/hase/simjava/distributions/doc/eduni/distributions/Weibull.html
- http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/PsRandom.html

One way to generate a random number from a given distribution is to generate a random number uniformly distributed between zero and one, and apply the target distribution's inverse [CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) to that random number. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Comment: Thank you so much! The flanagan library is exactly what I want! Saves me having to create my own algorithms. Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 0):

For your case, something like this:

```
 Random generator = new Random();
 double r = Math.sqrt(-Omega*Math.log(1-generator.nextDouble()));
```