# Generates rayleigh distribution using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I try to simulate http workload that obeys rayleigh distribution. I wish to use jmeter for that. I know how to utilize the Poisson and Gaussian Random Timers and I wonder if you have an idea of how to use a raleigh-based timer.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to implement the algorithm using for example:

- [JSR223Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Timer/JSR223Timer.html)
- Groovy as a language in the timer
- And one of those algorithm implementations:
  [How to generate a random number with a specific probability density function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729243/how-to-generate-a-random-number-with-a-specific-probability-density-function)

**EDIT 2/08/2016:**

You used the BeanShell (JSR223+Groovy would perform much better) option to utilize the Apache commons.math3 library.

Sample code:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.WeibullDistribution; 
alpha = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("alpha")); 
beta = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("beta")); 
rng= Integer.parseInt(bsh.args[0]); 
try { 
    WeibullDistribution g= new WeibullDistribution(rng, alpha,beta);    
    return g.sample(); 
} catch (Throwable ex) { 
    log.error("Something wrong", ex); 
    throw ex; 
}
```

Comment: Thats is helpful! I used the BeanShell option to utilize the commons.math3 library. import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.WeibullDistribution;

alpha = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("alpha"));
beta = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("beta"));
rng= Integer.parseInt(bsh.args[0]);

try {
    WeibullDistribution g= new WeibullDistribution(rng, alpha,beta);
    return g.sample();
}
catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Something wrong", ex);
    throw ex;
}

Comment: If so, you should accept my answer and upvote it so that other users can use it. Feel free to amend it with your comment. Thx